# Identify those arcade games from a 1983 Brazilian music video

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc29wmxJ_Ug) is a music video, recorded around 1982/1983, from [Kodiak Bachine](https://monkeybuzz.com.br/materias/kodiak-bachine-alpa-kamashka-e-o-relancamento-de-mumia/), considered to be the first Brazilian synthpop musician.

At 5:39 you can see what looks like an arcade game:
[image]

and at 5:50 another racing game where I can make out a [Taito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taito_of_Brazil) logo - Google reverse image search says it's [Pole Position II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_Position_II):

[image]

Can someone ID those games from the (very low quality) screen grabs? I would place them at the early 80s, seeing as Brazil was at the time a country with a very closed and limited market and older arcade machines could often be found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The top game (actually both) is [Sega's Turbo from 1981](https://thekingofgrabs.com/2023/02/07/turbo-arcade/)

[image: Sega Turbo 1981]

[See it in action on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69iLOuRoU5Y)

Comment: The bottom one is also Turbo, at about 9:14 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-miyT1Vz1w

Comment: that was an easy one for a change :)